# Error: Syntax error. Missing ')' for CASE Statement

Tags: formula, text, compile-error

I've created a text formula field, but I've been hitting a wall with the CASE portion of the formula: I keep getting the "Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'" message. Here's what I created:

```
Account.Name & 

 CASE(RecordType.Id, 01260000000UHnk, ' - Customer Support SLA - ', 
                    01260000000Q5Ok, ' - Renewal SLA - ', 
                    ' - Non-Standard SLA - '
     ) & 

TEXT(MONTH(Contract.StartDate))+"/" +TEXT(DAY(Contract.StartDate))+"/" +TEXT(YEAR(Contract.StartDate))
```

Everything seems to be in order, but I cannot figure out what's missing. Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the record type ids in quotes and see if it works, I think that may be your issue here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ID values also need to be in quotes. The error is a bit of a red herring; it's just how the parser reports errors.

Comment: Perfect - this worked! Gotta love a platform that utilizes literary devices in error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be on the values of the Id field and that it needs to be enclosed within quotes as well:

```
CASE(RecordType.Id, 
    '01260000000UHnk', ' - Customer Support SLA - ', 
    '01260000000Q5Ok', ' - Renewal SLA - ', 
    ' - Non-Standard SLA - '
 )
```